# LINQ - Join a table with another only when an outer condition satisfies

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am having a task to join a table with another.

```
Table 1: some data with Table1Id column.
Table 2: some data with Table2Id column.
Table 3: some data with Table3Id column.
```

Now I want to join Table1 with Table2.
But here I want to join Table1 with Table3 only if condition satisfies.
If the condition does not satisfy, the table should not be included only.
How is it possible in LINQ is questionable.

Example:

```
var data = (from temp in Table1 join temp2 in Table2 on temp.Table1Id equals temp2.Table2Id
           select temp).ToList();
```

Here, In the query itself I want to check the condition and based on condition I want to join the Table1 and Table2 to Table3.  And, this condition is not based on Table columns but an outer condition.

Step1 : join table1 to table2.
Step2 ; if(outer contition == "Yes join Table3")
           then  join Table3.
Any advice or suggestion will be thankful.
English is not my native language so please NO OFFENCE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Joins With Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657975/conditional-joins-with-linq)

Comment: If my condition does not satisfy then the table itself is not considered for join. I mean, I am not going for checking the data of column, The data of the column should only be checked when my condition satisfies.

Comment: Could you provide some data and expect result?

Comment: *Please* don't use LINQ as if it were a replacement for SQL. It's not. It's a query language used on top of an ORM. It deals with *entities*, not tables. You *entities* should have relations and navigation properties, defined either through conventions, attributes or DbContext configuration. The *ORM* will generate the joins. If you have a Customer and Orders property, your `Customer` class should have an `Orders` property. *The ORM* will generate the LEFT OUTER join that will return the orders for a specific customer

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
Step1: Join Table1 and Table2 and save it in a variable, say XYZ
Step2: Join XYZ and Table3 based on condition and save

```
    var XYZ = (from temp in Table1 join temp2 in Table2 on temp.Table1Id equals temp2.Table2Id
               select temp).ToList();
    if condition ()
    {
        var data = (from temp in XYZ join temp3 in Table3 on temp.Table1Id equals temp2.Table2Id
               select temp).ToList();
   }
```

**Method 2:**
Use left join on table3. In linq you can use GroupJoin for this

Comment: I don't want to do this separately. In my task I have a huge number of columns, and doing it separately will not give the efficiency that I am looking for. My question was, is it possible to check this condition within the query?